# Argument Not Optional Error for AutoFilter code

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am not terribly well-versed in VBA. I am trying to create a macro that filters the table of the active sheet for 0 and "N/A". When running the macro I get the error "Argument Not Optional" and refers back to ws.Range line.

I have looked over others code and I am unsure of what exactly I have done wrong.

```vb
Sub Remove_Cleared()
'
' Remove_Rows_Based_On_Value
'

'
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim activeTable As String

    activeTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name

    MsgBox activeTable 'Make sure pulling correct table

    'Set reference to the sheet in the workbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Activate 'not required but allows user to view sheet if warning message

    'clear any existing filters
    On Error Resume Next
        ws.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

    '1 Apply Filter
    ws.Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="N/A"

    '2 Delete Rows
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ws.Range(activeTable).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    '3 Clear Filter
    On Error Resume Next
        ws.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

By the end of the macro I would like any row containing a value of 0 or N/A to be removed from the active sheet's table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ws.Range("A1:M300")` ... The `Range` object requires a range.

Since you are already getting that table's name, you can use that as argument:

```vb
ws.Range(activeTable).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="N/A"
```

Comment: It is still showing the same error and highlighting the same line of code.

Comment: @Stephanie I have just tested your all code, with the correction I've proposed and works fine... have you updated the line? And if yes, can you share the workbook, I`ll be happy to have a look what else is going wrong.

Comment: I did update it. I ended up copying the whole macro into a new workbook and now it works fine. Thank you for your help!